# What would be the Torah view on Kibud Av vEm when requested to constantly cater to them?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

If a parent regularly asks to be accompanied to multiple places by car during the day and this would use a large portion of the day, is the child required to fulfill this all the time even if it conflicts with the child's schedule?